# Span's pseudo-elements overlay the element itself

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm stuck with CSS pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` when I was trying to stylize button's background. The problem is this: when I'm using only positive z-indices to place `span` itself and its pseudo-elements in right order, `:before` and `:after` are always overlapping the element. When I'm using negative z-indices, it's all right, but I don't want to change other underlying elements' z-indices just to make the button working.

So [that's](http://jsfiddle.net/VLLjc/) the problem and [that's](http://jsfiddle.net/pLQNv/1/) the goal to be achieved except the negative z-indices.

Problem code:

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index:3;
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    top: 25px;
    height: 60px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background: rgb(96,96,100);
    border: 1px solid #202020;
    color: #dddddd;
}

.button:before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(85,85,90, .7);
    padding: 10px;
    left: -10px;
    top: -10px;
}

.button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(85,85,90, .4);
    padding: 20px;
    left: -20px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go for borders ! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/RwGV9/1/

basically

```
border:solid 10px rgba(85,85,90, .7);
left: -10px;
top: -10px;
```

and same thing for the other one with the right left, top and padding !

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/D8gDK/

```
.button {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
left: 25px;
top: 25px;
width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;
background: rgb(96,96,100);
border: 1px solid #202020;
color: #dddddd;
}
.button:before {
content: "";
display: block;
width: 140px;
height: 60px;
position: relative;
background: rgba(85,85,90, .7);
border: 10px solid rgba(85,85,90, .4);
padding: 10px;
left: -40px;
top: -20px;
}
```

I got rid of the second pseudo element and put the before behind the button.
Might need some work with the colors...

Works only if you know the width of the button, though

Comment: You didn't get my point, I want to know is it possible to do that without using negative z-index.

Comment: the `:before` will always be displayed at the z-index level of its element. Using an absolute positioning puts it on top of it. So I would say that is not possible. Just not to my knowledge. I try to play around with it some more.

Comment: But, if so, what's the difference between negative z-index sequences and positive ones?

Comment: Negative ones bring you behind the original Element. Positive ones will always be in front of it, because they are taken relative to the original element.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind putting attributes in your html, you could do like that :

http://jsfiddle.net/RwGV9/

in the HTML :

```
<span data-text='button !' class="button">button</span>
```

and in the CSS :

```
.button:before {
content: attr(data-text);
```

Basically put the text in the highest layer using button using content: attr(); and make you text disappear in the deepest one (bg color = type color is not very elegant but it keeps the text of the button selectable for the user !)

Comment: Good suggestion, but the problem is that I don't have direct access to html cause it's generated by Vaadin. Likewise, it's one of the reasons to use only positive z-indices.